# C: is there any way to prevent open a file repeatedly?

Tags: c, linux

I want that each file can only be opened at most once at a time. For example, I have such a c file

```
int main()
{
  const char *filename = "test";
  fun1();
  fun2();
  ...
}

void fun1()
{
  fd_1 = open(filename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND, 0666);
}

void fun2()
{
  fd_2 = open(filename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND, 0666);
}
```

i.e. to prevent fun2 to open `test` before the file_descriptor of it has closed the file. I there any way to do this? (except scan the directory `fd/`)

Comment: Open the file in `main()` and pass the *file descriptor* around instead of the file name.

Comment: this is very unclear - can you provide more detail?  when are you closing fd_1? where is fd_1 declared? why do you need to reopen it? what do fun1 and fun2 do? otherwise do like @pmg suggested.

Comment: This could help you, in general : http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html

Comment: If all this happens in the same program, then you know when each file is opened and closed, so where is the problem? When are these file closed?

Comment: this doesn't even compile. `filename` is a local variable in `main` so you can't use it in any other functions

Comment: You could store the name of already opened files in some structure, maybe protected by some locks in case you'll use multiple threads. In each function check first if the name is stored in the structure, if it is make the function fail or wait on a condition variable.

Answer (score 2):

There is no portable way to determine if a file is already open. You cannot use `O_EXCL` for your purpose, because you do not want to create a new file.

A simple solution for your purpose, appending to a log file, is to open the file in `O_APPEND` mode in `main` and pass the handle to both `fun1` and `fun2`, or make it a global variable. Depending on the details of `fun1` and `fun2`, and if there are nested calls, the output into the log file might be mixed in an undesired fashion. Reorganising the output functions may be required for this problem.